# Set Session variable using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, session-variables

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkQuery()
    {
      var val = form1.proDown.options[form1.proDown.options.selectedIndex].value;
      var txt = form1.proDown.options[form1.proDown.options.selectedIndex].text;
      //alert(val+' | '+txt);
      <?php $_SESSION['value1']= ?> = txt; <?php ; ?>
     }
   </script>
```

I have this code and it does not Work?
Any One have solution for accessing javascript variable into $_SESSION[].

Comment: 1. welcome to SO. 2. ignore the downvoters that do not comment. 3. please, explain your question more in detail. What do you want to achieve? what does "it does not work" mean really?

Comment: i dont see connection between your code and setting session? have you look at php session tutorials? One is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: wait,you want to acccess to php session from javascript?

Comment: who are you to give me down votes ? @TheBronx

Comment: I've not downvoted the question. Downvoting without commenting is just trolling. And downvoting newbies without commenting is doubletrolling :P But please, take your time to write the question properly, read the comments and edit your question to add more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use xhr(Ajax) to store your data into php session. Following is a simple example to do this

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'storesession.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            txt: txt,
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(data); // do with data e.g success message
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus.reponseText);
        }
    });
```

storesession.php

```
$_SESSION['value1'] = $_POST['txt'];
```

Comment: Probably an obvious thing to point out, but in case any reads this and doesn't realise - if you need to store anything that people shouldn't be changing, you need to add additional security and/or validation. For instance, don't use this for logging in a user and setting their UserId in the session! Anyone could spoof a call to your PHP script, it's not only your page's javascript that can access it.

Comment: I guess it's not too bad if "value1" is hardcoded like he did, and if value1 is not really all that important... But yeah, NEVER, EVER do somehting like $_SESSION[$_POST['variableName']] = $_POST['variableValue'];, that would let anybody set any variable to any value they want :O