# Reset the modal reveal after close

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, reveal.js, jquery-1.7

I have a modal in the template header.php:

```
<div id="modalRv">
   <?php echo $_SESSION['test']; ?>
   <a class='close'>Close</a>
</div>
```

This div is loaded only one time. In this template I do :

```
('a.close').on('click', function() {
    $('#modalRv').trigger('reveal:close');
});
```

In the .js I do :

```
('#modalRv').reveal({              //  The  item  which  will  be  opened  with  reveal
    animation: 'fade',             //  fade,  fadeAndPop,  none
    animationspeed: 600,           //  how  fast  animtions  are
    closeonbackgroundclick: true,  //  if  you  click  background  will  modal  close?
    dismissmodalclass:  'close'    //  the  class  of  a  button  or  element  that  will  close  an  open  modal
});
```

The idea is that template is loaded only one time but the value of `$_SESSION['test']` change for each call, but i get only the value of start. I tried to do :

```
$('#modalRv').html("");
```

but the same situation. Sorry for my english. Thx in advance

Comment: You seem to be missing the `$` on a couple of your jQuery objects.

Comment: This might help you [Set Session variable using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067335/set-session-variable-using-javascript)